# Slider using HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

I'm getting a bit frustrated in aligning the images in this slider. I've been playing around with its CSS but to no avail, I can't position the images right. The images that I'm using are 1920x1080 pixels in size. (But I change the pictures in this post).

Here is a snippet where i changed the images to imageholders just to be better to visualize, please, take a look.

```css
.slider-holder{
           width: 100%;
           height: 670px;
           background-color: yellow;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-top: 0px;
           text-align: center;
           overflow: hidden;
       }

       .image-holder{
           width: 1920px;
           background-color: red;
           height: 670px;
           clear: both;
           position: relative;

           -webkit-transition: left 2s;
           -moz-transition: left 2s;
           -o-transition: left 2s;
           transition: left 2s;
       }

       .slider-image{
           float: left;
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
           position: relative;
       }

       #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: 0px;
       }

       #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: -800px;
       }

       #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: -1600px;
       }

       .button-holder{
           position: relative;
           top: -20px;
       }

       .slider-change{
           display: inline-block;
           height: 10px;
           width: 10px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           background-color: brown;
       }
```

```html
    <div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more technical details about what *"I can't position images right"* and *"I've been playing with CSS"* mean?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of pure css sliders out there: https://corpocrat.com/2015/12/09/20-cool-pure-css-sliders-without-jqueryjavascript/ I'd suggest looking at the code examples. There's not much point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I changed somethings, first of all, I needed to change the placeholders, it was so hard to work with so big images

Than I changed the position of the buttons, put `position: relative`in `.slider-holder` and than `position: absolute`in `.button-holder` so I can position it in center bottom.

in `.image-holder` I used `display: flex` so it prevent the images to break line, they will always be side by side

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2q74re6s/7/

```css
.slider-holder{
           width: 200px;
           height: 200px;
           background-color: yellow;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-top: 0px;
           text-align: center;
           overflow: hidden;
           position: relative;
       }

       .image-holder{
           width: 200px;
           background-color: red;
           height: 200px;
           clear: both;
           position: relative;
           -webkit-transition: left 2s;
           -moz-transition: left 2s;
           -o-transition: left 2s;
           transition: left 2s;
           display: flex;
       }

       .slider-image{
           float: left;
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
           position: relative;
       }

       #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: 0px;
       }

       #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: -200px;
       }

       #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder{
           left: -400px;
       }

       .button-holder{
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           left: 50%;
           transform: translateX(-50%);
       }

       .slider-change{
           display: inline-block;
           height: 10px;
           width: 10px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           background-color: brown;
       }
```

```html
<div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/201x201" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/202x202" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```